# Best practices/advices to develop SSIS with remote SQL Servers over VPN

Tags: sql-server, vpn, sql-server-data-tools

I'm in a consulting team of 4 that develops ETL packages for a client using Data Tools against multiple SQL Servers (a single package can connect to SQL 2016, 2017 and 2019). We used to develop in a "jump box" that is on the same network as those servers (coordinating to connect only 2 max at a time, by RDP restrictions), but our client shut down that box stating that from now on we must only use the VPN and do all the work locally on our machines because "it is the best practice". Of course our personal machines are faster running the Data Tools IDE and we don't have to fight for connection to the jump box, but when we debug our packages the data flows are so slow and we can't turn off the machine until the process ends. Also the VPN is shaky and we lose connection from time to time. So my question is: is this really the correct approach and we are missing something, or should we push to have the jump box back? Are there "best practices" to develop against remote SQL Servers, regarding where the solution should reside and how we should extract the data? Thanks and sorry if this question doesn't make much sense, but we are struggling now to develop our packages.

Comment: Shouldn't you be developing your packages against local copies of the client database?

Comment: That's a good idea, but then we would need to purchase a big server to install 3 versions of SQL Server to replicate the environments, also the databases are of several TB. Anyway we'll ask our client if he's OK to give us backups because there is sensitive data in them.